# Get a location image from Google Map with a mark (for free)

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to get pictures like this

[image]

to my android app by knowing lat and lon. What is the best way? I stopped reading the documentation after was asked to create a billing account (not sure I willing to pay for this).

Comment: You have to crate a billing account. You will get free API call of $300 after connecting to your billing account. You have to provide info of your credit card and a minuscule amount will be deducted to verify the authentication of your card.

Please go through this link for the billing info:
https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions

Answer (score 1):

You can read the documentation without creating a billing account.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map-with-marker

This documentation helps you creating a marker and moving a camera view.

Comment: Sorry, if I was unclear, but I meant getting this image without `YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: Okay, if you need just the "image", then I recommend you to take a screen shot of the place you want from Google Map (web based) and put it in a imageview. If you want to show that image on Android Google Map instance, then you must get an API key.

Comment: That is what I'm doing right now, but still, I hoping for an easiest way

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map sdk on lite mode(It basically loads static image without any pinching feature), and its dynamic with lat lang so you can use an image like map even for any lat long value.